# How can i make argparse suparser match any string?

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

i am using

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparser = parser.add_subparsers()


add_parser = subparsers.add_parser("add", help="Add parser")

add_parser.add_argument("-project", default="global")


edit_parser = subparsers.add_parser("edit", help="Edit parser")
```

I want to achieve smething like this:

1. python myprogram.py add
2. python myprogram.py edit
3. python myprogram.py "A random string"

Where in the first two usecases my program can asign the right subparser based on the keyword "add" or "edit".  I am interested in the last case, where it maps to any random string that i provide.

Comment: It would help if you format your code as code. To do this, select all of your code and press Ctrl-K

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way of doing this.  The use of subparsers is an extension of a `positional` argument with `choices`.

```
parser.add_argument('cmd', choices=['add', 'edit', ...])
```

It accepts a string if it is `in choices`.  There isn't a builtin pattern matching mechanism.

I think your simplest solution would be to add one step:

```
custom = subparser.add_parser('custom', help='give a random string')
custom.add_argument('anystring', help='random quoted string')

python myprogram.py custom 'any random string'
```

I can imagine writing a custom `choices` class that could do both kinds of matching.  It would require a custom `__contains__` method (and maybe a new `__iter__` to list choices in the help). But incorporating that into the `_SubParsersAction` class would require some serious coding.

---

A few more details.  Your `subparser` object is an `_SubParsersAction`.  Its `choices` attribute is an OrderedDict.  When you `add_parser`, it creates a new `ArgumentParser` (the `add_parser` object), and enters it into the dict with the named key (plus any aliases).  When parsing your input, `argparse` matches the strings against the keys of this dictionary.  So, to implement your ideal, you'd have to change this dictionary lookup.

---

Another option is to look at `sys.argv[1:]` at the start.  If one of your 'cmds' is present call the `parser` to get the full subparser action.  Otherwise handle the inputs yourself, or call another `parser` that handles 'a random string' as an ordinary positional argument.  Sometimes it just isn't worth the effort to twist `argparse` into a special shape.